# Effectively revert to a previous commit in Sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to actually revert to a previous commit, effectively cancelling every change that has been made after it, and making this previous commit the current one, at the top of the list.

But when I use the function "Reset current branch to this commit", I am then unable to do anything until I pull back all of the commits I am trying to cancel.

I feel like a lot of people have been asking that exact same question in the comments of other posts, but they never receive a clear answer. What is the procedure for doing this?

Comment: Have you pushed the commits you were trying to cancel? Did your .gitignore file(s) change between the commits? Did you choose soft, hard or mixed for "Reset current branch to this commit"?

Comment: Yes they have all been pushed, no the gitignore files have not changed. I chose the "Hard" method for the reset.
I don't really want to cancel or delete the following commits. Ideally I could just checkout that commit, and then commit/push it back to git.

Comment: In that case I would open the terminal, and type e.g. `git checkout c17c46e ./` (replace `c17c46e` with the actual commit hash), then commit the results and push it to the remote. It won't delete the history, just change the files (under `./`, so it's every tracked file) to that previous commit and then you can create a new commit with the same files. You need the `./` otherwise it will perform an ordinary checkout and create a detached head.

Comment: I mean, I wouldn't use "Reset current branch to this commit" at all in that case, but rather open the Terminal and type in the command as described above. Also, you don't have to type the SHA manually, you can right click and 'Copy SHA to Clipboard'.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much. If you write this solution as a answer I will mark it as the accepted answer for everybody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want to cancel/delete the following commits, I wouldn't use "Reset current branch to this commit" at all in that case.

I would open the Terminal and enter `git checkout c17c46e ./` (replace `c17c46e` with the actual commit hash).

The files under `./` (i.e. all the tracked files) will be changed to their older states.
The `./` is necessary so that it doesn't simply switch to an earlier position and create a detached head.

Also, the commit hash doesn't have to be typed manually, as you can right click a commit and click 'Copy SHA to Clipboard'.

After running that command, you can commit the results and push it to the remote.

Comment: I found that the slash is actually optional, you can do something like `git checkout c17c46e .`